# pdfcomment and breqn

Tags: breqn, pdfcomment

I'm trying to use `\pdfmarkupcomment` from `pdfcomment` inside a `dmath` environment from `breqn`, but they appear to be incompatible.

Here is a simple example where it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% this works
\begin{equation}
\pdfmarkupcomment{ab}{F}
\end{equation}

% this fails:
\begin{dmath}
\pdfmarkupcomment{cd}{G}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

The error I get from pdflatex is:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `pdfcomment:zref@2' on page 1 undefined on input line 
18.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \kern -\parskip \leavevmode \vadjust 
                                                {\vbox to\z@ {\vss \@mn@marg...
l.18 \pdfmarkupcomment{cd}{G}

? 

LaTeX Warning: Reference `pdfcomment:zref@3' on page 1 undefined on input line 
18.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux
* soulpos - computing points - it may take a few seconds * (./test.upa))

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

I'm compiling in (k)ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  I suggest you load `breqn` _after_ `pdfcomment` to alleviate one warning message.  But that doesn't solve your main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, `breqn` redefines in certain situations `\vadjust` to be `\eq@vadjust` without giving any meaning to this command, and this is the reason why you get the puzzling error message.

My suggestion would be to drop `breqn` altogether: I don't think it's useful to improve typography; it possibly can help in case where automatic breaking is desired because we can't control it (say mass compilation of documents whose output quality is not a concern).

If you add a default meaning to `\eq@vadjust` the document compiles, but I can't check if this has adverse effects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\eq@vadjust}{\@@vadjust}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{equation}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline]{ab}{F}
\end{equation}

\begin{dmath}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline]{cd}{G}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot drop breqn. It is used to break some long equations which are automatically generated by another program. Your suggestion does appear to make it work. So far I have not spotted any visible issues. Thank you!